# C# JsonIgnore to basic class

Tags: c#, json, mvvm-light

I have class

```
public class SettingsExpires : ViewModelBase
{
    private int? frequency;
    [JsonProperty("frequency")]
    public int? Frequency
    {
        get => frequency;
        set => this.Set(ref frequency, value);
    }
}
```

Where `ViewModelBase` is `abstract` class from GalaSoft.MvvmLight
My problem start when I try serialize my class to json and get this:

```
{{  "frequency": null, "IsInDesignMode": false}}
```

I get `IsInDesignMode` from basic class `ViewModelBase`

```
public bool IsInDesignMode { get; }
```

How can I ignore this property from base class ?
I tried something like this:

```
public class SettingsExpires : ViewModelBase
{
    private int? frequency;
    [JsonProperty("frequency")]
    public int? Frequency
    {
        get => frequency;
        set => this.Set(ref frequency, value);
    }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public new bool IsInDesignMode { get; }
}
```

or this:

```
public class SettingsExpires : ViewModelBase
{
    private int? frequency;
    [JsonProperty("frequency")]
    public int? Frequency
    {
        get => frequency;
        set => this.Set(ref frequency, value);
    }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsInDesignMode { get; }
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried to decorate your `SettingsExpires` class with `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By decorating your derived class (`SettingsExpires`) with the following attribute:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
```

you are basically instructing the serializer to include only those properties which are explicitly annotated with `JsonProperty`. Everything else will be ignored.

[Reference](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOptIn.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You could define a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) to ignore the properties. For example,

```
public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.DeclaringType == typeof(ViewModelBase) && property.PropertyName == "IsInDesignMode")
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = x=> false;
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

Now you could serialize your data by specifying the contract resolver.

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    data,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver() }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Anu Viswan gave (IMHO) a very good solution.

Alternately, you could use the attribute [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)] on top of your class(es) to serialize, which will give you the ability to choose clearly which fields you want to serialize.

But it has a drawback : you will have to put the [JsonProperty] on every property you want in JSON.
Very handful for some cases, but it can be tedious if you have a lot of classes to serialize.

You can choose which solution looks to be the best for you :)